# Django multiple profiles using auth.User. Standard student teacher example

Tags: django, relational-database

Is it correct way to create 2 profiles in django? I want student to have access to his teachers, and teacher to his students as well. I mean if I log in as a student, I want to browse exactly teachers who teach me, and if I log in as a teacher, I want to browse exactly students which I teach. That is way I rather can not create one profile for both teachers and students.

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Student(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    teacher = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher)
```

if so, my AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE should look that way?

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'school.Teacher, school.Student'
```

would be grateful for any answers.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a single profile;

```
class People(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField("self")
```

Then you can access the necessary information with;

```
teacher = People.objects.get(pk=<teacher_pk>)
students = People.objects.filter(teachers=teacher)

student = People.objects.get(pk=<student_pk>)
teachers = student.teachers.all()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And I assume that is the correct way to do that? Or both ones are correct in some circumstances?

Comment: I'd agree that it does depend on the circumstance